# Python Dask causes an error when combining requests

Tags: python, dask

When I am following best practice on Dask by combining the compute request, I get an error. If I don't combine the compute request, it works fine.

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#avoid-calling-compute-repeatedly

```py
xmin, xmax = client.compute(df.price.min(), df.price.max())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/***/code/dask/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 2929, in compute
    if sync:
  File "/Users/***/code/dask/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 199, in __bool__
    "a conditional statement.".format(self)
TypeError: Trying to convert dd.Scalar<series-..., dtype=int64> to a boolean value. Because Dask objects are lazily evaluated, they cannot be converted to a boolean value or used in boolean conditions like if statements. Try calling .compute() to force computation prior to converting to a boolean value or using in a conditional statement.
```

If I do the requests individually, it works:

```py
df['price'].max().compute()
df['price'].min().compute()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post the complete code

Comment: `dask.compute` is not the same as `client.compute`. Take a look at the API docs for `Client.compute`, and this should become clear. You need to pass the dask collections in an iterable